# prerendering in react_on_rails app is throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-on-rails

Whenever I switch prerendering to true for my react component in my rails view I'm getting this error

```
undefined local variable or method `e' for ReactOnRails::ServerRenderingPool::Exec:Class
```

I've found on the shakacode site that there's a typo in lib/react_on_rails/server_rendering_pool/exec.rb

but I don't know how to access that file - it's nowhere in my directory - am I completely missing something here?

Comment: That file is not in your directory because it is in the react_on_rails gem directory. https://rubygems.org/gems/react_on_rails is where you can find more information about the gem, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed already on: https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/pull/1020